# share php session

Tags: php, session

I recently  ran in a problem and I've been trying to resolve it with out any luck. I'm, trying to share the php session across several servers php/apache level on all server using GlusterFS,however, although the session is accessible on all servers the session does not get transfer once I hit a different sever. I get logged off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, when people want to use load-balancing, and they want one user balanced to several servers, they store sessions :

- either using a database, which is accessible from every web-servers
- or using something like [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) -- which is a distributed cache server (and really works well when you want to store that kind of temporary data, and you have several servers that need to access it).

I don't know about GlusterFS *(I have actually never heard of it)*, but I've seen sessions stored in either database and memcached, and those work quite fine.

Would one of those solutions not be OK for you ?

Comment: +1. You should use your own session handling if you're developing for a server cluster.

Comment: +1 These are the tried and true approaches here.  Unless OP has some weird requirement he's not telling us about, he should follow Pascal's advice.