# Forbid use of PHP file by unwanted Client-side requests

Tags: php, authorization, file-access

I've a PHP document, let's say jsonarray.php.

This file returns the json_encode of an associative array when some parameters are given.
I need to forbid an unwanted user to access and use this file for his own purposes.

Is this possible?

In addition, I want to specify that it is a client-side request, which I make in a JavaScript code.

Comment: How are the parameters given? `GET`?

Comment: Yes, it is a get Request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are looking this from another PHP file, you can set `BASEPATH` constant there & add the following line in top of all the files you need to protect:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

so if the file is accessed from that particular file, `BASEPATH` is set & everything works. But incase of some url directly tried to access, script would terminate.

If you are calling it this from Javascript -- other option is
to add `nonce` token to every javascript request which is basically a randomly generated unique token that is valid for single request. see [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) for more details.

here is a example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084795/single-use-csrf-token-generation-and-validation-for-cross-server-communication-i):

```
    function create_api_key(){
        return base64_encode(base64_encode($this->encrypt(time().'X'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
    }

    function check_api_key($key,$timeout=5){
        if(empty($key)){ exit('Invalid Key'); }

        $keys=explode('X',$this->decrypt(base64_decode(base64_decode($key))));

        if (isset($key) && isset($keys[0]) && $keys[0] >= (time()-$timeout) &&
        isset($keys[1]) && $keys[1] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function encrypt($value){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 'SECURE_KEY', $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    }

    function decrypt($value){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 'SECURE_KEY', $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    }
}

$csrf = new csrf_check();

if(!empty($_GET['do'])){

    $do = $_GET['do'];
    switch($do){
            //example.com?do=get - a key for the request
        case "get":
            echo $csrf->create_api_key();
            break;

        case "check":
            //key only lasts 30 secs & validate key passed
            //example.com?do=get&key=MEV6NXk4UjVRQXV5Qm1CMjBYa3RZZUhGd2M0YnFBUVF0ZkE5TFpNaElUTT0=
            if(!empty($_GET['key']) && $csrf->check_api_key($_GET['key'],30)){
                exit('Key valid');
            }else{exit('Key invalid');}
            break;

        default:
            exit('Request invalid');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if i generate a `nonce` in my JS, how can I check its correctness? My php file doesn't know it. (If it is a fixed value then it's useless). Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Added example code, you can use this or one of that many [PHP CSRF protection libary](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=csrf+php+library)

Comment: Ok, i tried to implement this, but now that I've finished I'm encountering some issues: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is different because i call the get on client and the check is performed by the server. I tried changing `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` with a string, but i get nonvalid key message.

Comment: OK, it seems that everything is fine, after a long reading I also changed the requests to POST

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as requiring a specific `$_GET` parameter might be enough for you -

```
if (isset($_GET['password']) && $_GET['password'] == "your_password"){

}else{
  die('access denied!');
}
```

Now all you have to do to be able to access this PHP file is to add the password in to the URL :

> `http://yourcoolsite.com/jsonarray.php?password=your_password`

I would recommend *not* using "password" as the key for the parameter. Rather call it something else, something slightly obfuscated so that it is not immediately apparent that it is a password.

> `http://yourcoolsite.com/jsonarray.php?mpwyour_password`

Comment: This won't work because if I make a getJSON in JS, password is easily detectable since I've to pass it as a parameter in the data payload

Comment: @vek - you'll want to add the fact that it is normally a client side request to your question...

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

No.

Because as you make a request from javascript to that file it must be accessible to the browser. As you don't control the browser you can not say any longer if the javascript in th browser initiated the request or something or somebody else.

Comment: The best you can do is slow down the use by introducing the additional complexity of single-use tokens.

Comment: Which can be counter productive for client-side interaction. Better is to have authenticated sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use `.htaccess` to prevent users from directly viewing a file
Here's two links to a find out how: [Tutorial 1](http://biostall.com/prevent-direct-file-access-using-a-htaccess-file) [Tutorial 2](http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#sec2)

Answer (score -2):

Why not just check for whatever requirements you need and if they are not met then kill the page.

```
die('Access Blocked');
```

Comment: Because this doesn't prevent file access from anywho.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote? The OP changed the question after I answered!

Comment: @Vektor88 I know, you cannot yet, you have not reaches the min!! ;)